# Name node always nil - ARKit Swift

Tags: swift, scenekit, arkit

I'm trying to receive the name node associated to the node tapped through "hitTest" but every time that I'm doing tap on a node, the name is nil.

This is the function where I'm creating the nodes and associating the name to them:

```
private func findLocalPlaces(topics: [Topic]) {

    guard let location = self.locationManager.location else {
        return
    }

    for topic in topics {
        let topicLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: topic.coordinates!.x, longitude: topic.coordinates!.y)
        let locationPin = CLLocation(coordinate: topicLocation, altitude: location.altitude)
        //Set the image of the pin
        let urlImage = topic.image?.image(topicId: topic._id, imageType: .mobileHeader)
        Alamofire.request(urlImage ?? "").responseImage { response in
            if let image = response.result.value {

                //self.annotationNode = LocationAnnotationNode(location: locationPin, image: image)

                //Create a view instead of the only image view
                let viewDemo = UIView()
                viewDemo.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 500, height: 281)

                let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
                imageView.frame = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: viewDemo.frame.size)
                viewDemo.addSubview(imageView)

                let label = UILabel()
                label.textColor = .white
                label.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 200, width: 400, height: 30)
                label.text = topic.name
                viewDemo.addSubview(label)

                self.annotationNode.name = topic.name


                self.annotationNode = LocationAnnotationNode(location: locationPin, view: viewDemo)


                //Scale the POI based on the distance
                self.annotationNode.scaleRelativeToDistance = false

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    //Add the POI to the scene
                    self.sceneLocationView.addLocationNodeWithConfirmedLocation(locationNode: self.annotationNode)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The annotationNode is initialized to the top as:

```
var annotationNode: LocationAnnotationNode = LocationAnnotationNode(location: CLLocation(latitude: 0, longitude: 0), image: UIImage(named:"arPin")!)
```

EDIT

Code related to the hit test:

```
 //Method called when tap
@objc func handleTap(rec: UITapGestureRecognizer){

    if rec.state == .ended {
        let location: CGPoint = rec.location(in: sceneLocationView)
        let hits = self.sceneLocationView.hitTest(location, options: nil)
        if !hits.isEmpty{

            let tappedNode = hits.first?.node
            print("NODE TAPPED", tappedNode?.name)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you share the code where you perform the hitTest?

Comment: Sure I'm updating the question

Comment: And where in code you add gesture recognizer to your view?

Comment: In the viewDidLoad as:
 let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap(rec:)))
        sceneLocationView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

Comment: Uh, am i missing something or are you assigning a name to the node, and then override the whole node with a new node without a name?  `self.annotationNode.name = topic.name` and then


                `self.annotationNode = LocationAnnotationNode(location: locationPin, view: viewDemo)`

Comment: I'm assigning to annotationNode.name not to annotationNode

Comment: @Vollan is right though, you are first assigning a name and on the next line you're creating a new node. So it makes sense that `.name` is null.

Comment: Wrote it as an answer as well now.
@PietroMessineo yes but when you assign a new Node the name is included in the new one, causing it to be nil

Comment: You can't for instance do this: `let test: [String] = []` and then `test.append("foo")` and then `test = []` and expect it to have "foo" stored

Comment: That's right I haven't noriced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning a name to the node, and then override the whole node with a new node without a name?

You have a commented line at top after your `if let` and then you set name to `self.annotationNode` and then you override it, causing the naming to be useless. Remove the second:
`self.annotationNode = LocationAnnotationNode(location: locationPin, view: viewDemo)` and uncomment the first one

Answer (score 1):

You must be sure that your *hits* doesn't contain nil objects.

```
@objc func handleTap(rec: UITapGestureRecognizer){

    if rec.state == .ended {
        let location: CGPoint = rec.location(in: sceneLocationView)
        let hits = self.sceneLocationView.hitTest(location, options: nil).filter { $0.node.name != nil }
        if !hits.isEmpty{

            let tappedNode = hits.first?.node
            print("NODE TAPPED", tappedNode?.name)
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps!